# Rendering github file data to div

Tags: javascript, html, api, flask

Need some help. I fetched the contents of a file from the Github repo. Now I want to display the contents of the file in a div element in the same way as it is displayed in the file; the indentation should be the same. Currently, the whole file is being displayed in a single line.

```js
async function call() {
  let url = "https://api.github.com/repos/KushRohra/PythonProjects/contents/Basic_DSA_Codes/1. Two Number Sum.py";
  let response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  s = atob(data.content)
  console.log(s);
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = s;
}
call();
```

```html
<div id="code"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all the new line characters with `<br>` and all spaces with the corresponding number of `&nbsp;`:

```js
async function call() {
  let url = "https://api.github.com/repos/KushRohra/PythonProjects/contents/Basic_DSA_Codes/1. Two Number Sum.py";
  let response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  s = atob(data.content)
  console.log(s);
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = s.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;')
}
call();
```

```html
<div id="code"></div>
```